# Does play2-elasticsearch module support updates or upserts in elastic search?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, elasticsearch

I'm not finding any documentation or examples of the play2-elasticsearch module supporting the elasticsearch update api (specifically upsert).  Is this functionality supported in the latest version of play2-elasticsearch for play 2 framework? and Can some provide an example of how to use this functionality.